# while statement with a function

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a function

```
int is_true(int a[]){
    int is_true;

    if(a[0] != a[5]){
        is_true= 0;
    }else if(a[2] != a[4]){
        is_true= 0;
    }else{
        is_true= 1;
    }
    return is_true;
}
```

and I have another function where I want to insert a while loop, with the condition that as long as is_true = 0 it would keep going. but i keep getting this warning:

> comparison of function 'is_true’ equal to a null pointer is always
>   false [-Wtautological-pointer-compare]    pal.c   /exercise1  line 61 C/C++
>   Problem

my other function is

```
while(is_true == 0){
        c = getchar();

    if(c =='a'){
        if(p ==&a[0]){
            printf("Sorry, no more moves this way \n");
        }else{
        p--;
        printf("pointer is now at: %d\n ", *p);
        }
    }
    else if( c=='d'){
        p++;
        printf("pointer is now at: %d\n ", *p);
    }
    else if(c=='w'){
        (*p) = (*p+1);
        printf("the value is now: %d\n ", (*p));
    }
    else if(c=='s'){
                (*p) = (*p-1);
                printf("the value is now: %d\n ", (*p));
    }
}
```

Comment: change the name of the function.

Comment: You need to call the function, not just `is_true == 0`.

Comment: The error message you presented does not correspond to the code you presented.  Nowhere does the code perform a comparison involving any function (or variable) named `is_true`.

Comment: Possibly the error message is supposed to pertain to the `while` condition `(is_pal == 0)`.  If `is_pal` is a function, then you surely what you want to compare with zero is the result of *calling* that function.  If it accepts one parameter that is an array of `int`, then that would look like `while (is_pal(a) == 0)`.

Comment: thanks, got it working

Answer (score 4):

You have a function and a variable with the same name, `is_true`. Don't do that.

Comment: after I do that, in my second function, should i first call is_true() and then put the variable as my while condition?

Comment: I can't tell because the code prior to the call of that function is missing.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, certainly the OP's usage is stylistically questionable, but it's not wrong.  The local variable `is_true` shadows the function `is_true()` within the function body.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It's wrong because it makes it impossible for the OP to understand his own code. When you have more than one thing with the same name, compiler errors become incomprehensible to non-experts.

Answer (score 1):

your function `is_true` has a local variable with the same name.to fix the issue,simply change the function name to `f_is_true` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the identifier `is_true` that is visible to your while loop refers to the function `is_true()` that you presented, the error is pointing out that you are comparing a pointer to that function with a null pointer constant, which comparison will always evaluate to false.

What you want to do is surely to compare 0 with result of *calling* the function, which would look like this:

```
while (is_true(a) == 0) {
    /* ... */
}
```

, supposing that the desired argument is `a`.

Note that there is no inherent relationship between the function's local variables `a` and `is_true` and any variables of the same name anywhere else in the program.